# GeoDjango and Spatialite on Mac: issue with C extension Loading

Tags: django, sqlite, geodjango, pysqlite, spatialite

I'm following the [GeoDjango Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) to set up a dev spatial DB for my project on my home machine, a Mac Mini running OSX 10.8.2. I installed the KyngChaos packages (UnixImageIO, PROJ, GEOS, SQLite3 and GDAL) and spatialite as detailed in the [OSX section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/#spatialite-macosx) of the tutorial..

I created the database via spatialite, but when I try `python manage.py sqlall world` to check the model I get the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. Both SQLite and pysqlite must be configured to allow the loading of extensions to use SpatiaLite.`

There's not too much out there about this problem (and especially nothing for OSX) - most solutions involve installing pysqlite without the `define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` option  (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093593/python-the-pysqlite-library-does-not-support-c-extension-loading)). I tried with both spatialite 2.3.1 and 2.4, I patched and installed pysqlite in my virtualenv but I always get the same problem.

Both `spatialite` and `sqlite3` binaries seem to execute properly, and setting up a non-spatial sqlite database for django works fine too, so I doubt it's an issue with SQLite itself.

Any hints on how to get this working would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I have had much the same problem. Had no reply to my request for help on github... Maybe the pysqlite project is dead https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/60 I think I will have to use Postgres instead...