# Django: What is the way to store geometric figures?

Tags: python, django, geometry

What is the best way to store e.q. rectangles in Django? I was thinking about something like

```
start_position = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=10,
                                                   blank=True,
                                                   null=True)
heigh = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
                            null=True)
width = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
                            null=True)
```

in my model, but somehow this don't look correct. Is there a better way doing this? Would there be a way to have also collision detection maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Django's MultiWidget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511855/how-do-i-use-djangos-multiwidget)

Comment: Ah, linked the wrong thing... you can make your own field that is made up of multiple fields (finding link)

Comment: [Here's a small example of one](https://gist.github.com/elena/3915748) was making a version of an answer but I can't test it right now and it will involve some debugging to get working for your field..

Comment: I'm not sure whether I was really looking for something like the MultiWidget-feature which is cool beyond doubt. I think I had in my mind something like a Django app maybe offering also collision detection between two areas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GIS for your database, so in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME' : 'geodjango',
    }
}
```

And for your model.py, first import [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

Then make your model, for example:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    rectangle = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=900913, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

[GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/) should do all you need. In particular, a rectangle is a special case of a polygon, so this works:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Model, GeoManager, PolygonField

class MyModel(Model):
    rect = models.PolygonField()

    objects = GeoManager()

# the envelope polygon around two points is a rectangle
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point, GeometryCollection
rect = GeometryCollection(Point(10, 10), Point(20, 20)).envelope
MyModel.objects.create(rect=rect)
```

Lookup can be performed [directly on the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#spatial-queries) (possibly making use of spatial indexing):

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
p = Point(15, 15)
MyModel.objects.filter(rect__contains=p)
```

Note that GeoDjango requires additional libraries and --most importantly-- a database backend that supports spatial SQL. See the [setup guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#setting-up) for GeoDjango for details, but be wary when using sqlite as the default setup of spatiallite [might not work out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505665/install-spatialite-for-python-geodjango-on-os-x) without special install instructions.