# Stuck on pyenv with Django, sqlite and pysqlite with spatialite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, spatialite, pyspatialite

I have tries every combination of brew, Django, python and sqlite I can think of. Possible the built-in version of sqlite is messing with me.

I am trying to run the test suite for `django-geojson` (https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson).

The instructions are here:
https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson/issues/86

I keep running into this error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. Both SQLite and pysqlite must be configured to allow the loading of extensions to use SpatiaLite.`

I use macOS Sierra with brew, pyenv, various Python versions. Ask me if you need more info. I found several Google results from years ago that got me nowhere.

Comment: Tell use which Python version you are using, and if you could compile it yourself.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093593/python-the-pysqlite-library-does-not-support-c-extension-loading) - what happens when you update the .cfg and recompile - per [instructions here](http://technotes.tumblr.com/post/40838871308/django-with-sqlite-as-a-geospatial-database).

Comment: Where can I find the .cfg when installed through brew?

Comment: I used Python 2.7.10 and 3.4.6