# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SpatiaLite requires SQLite to be configured to allow extension loading

Tags: python, django, spatialite

I installed `spatialite` for `Django` project but when I try to migrate it show me this error :

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/spatialite/base.py", line 44, in get_new_connection
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SpatiaLite requires SQLite to be configured to allow extension loading.
```

I don't know how to figure out.
I tried   [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/)  by changing libexec/setuptools/setup.cfg file

```
[build_ext]
 #define=
include_dirs=/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/unix/include
library_dirs=/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/unix/lib
libraries=sqlite3
#define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
```

I have installed spatialite by brew then I changed the settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
}
SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.dylib'
```

Comment: It looks like improper configuration. Kindly check docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/

Comment: I have tried this but nothing works for me

Answer (score 5):

## The Issue

The `ImproperlyConfigured` error is raised in `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite.base` when using a Python build based on the default sqlite3 library - which is the case for MacOSX and probably most Linux distros - which was built with extension loading [disabled](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#f1). So, this won't work:

```
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.load_extension(SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

Following the directions of the [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/#spatialite-source) won't solve the problem in most cases. Even installing the `spatialite-tools` via [Homebrew](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/#homebrew) only installs new spatialite and sqlite executables and libraries in the Homebrew directory.

## The Solution

Assuming sqlite and spatialite are installed (e.g. via Homebrew) and the respective sqlite version has `load_extention` enabled, you can build Python from scratch with this sqlite library linked. It's pretty easy using pyenv. Specific build options can be provided via the `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS` environment variable (details [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/master/plugins/python-build)) and setting `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` (see [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems))

Building with pyenv assuming sqlite was installed via homebrew (check `which sqlite3`and `brew info sqlite` for details on which versions are installed and where):

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=\$(brew --prefix openssl)" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include" \
pyenv install 3.8.2
```

If dependencies are missing (e.g. openssl), see below on building Python manually.

Finally, it's important to reference the dynamically linked spatialite in your Django settings (so make sure `/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.dylib` exists)

```
SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.dylib'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.spatialite3'),
    }
}
```

### Build SQLite and Python manually

To compile sqlite from source with load extensions enabled  ([see docs](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)), download the amalgamated source file from the website and follow the instructions. You'll want to include the build option `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE` but **NOT** `-DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION`!

Once sqlite3 compiled, run the executable and check via the command `.dbconfig`

```
sqlite > .dbconfig
[...]
load_extension on
[...]
```

Loading extensions is turned off by default, to avoid [security issues](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension).

Building Python manually is also pretty straightforward and follows a similar pattern as installing via pyenv. Once dependencies are met (e.g. on [macos](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#macos) `brew install openssl xz gdbm`), you download the tarball with the desired version and set the compile options to enable sqlite extension loading (and telling make where to find your newly compiled SQLite build):

```
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)
LDFLAGS="-L<path-to-sqlite>" \
CPPFLAGS="-I<path-to-sqlite>" \
make -j2
```

## Other solutions (and other systems)

The described solution applied to MacOS primarily and Python3, since sqlite3 ships as part of the standard python library for Python3, as opposed to a seprate package for Python 2. Previous solutions, such as [pysqlite] only work for Python2 which is [EOL](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/).

What you tried may have been based on an [older solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093593/python-the-pysqlite-library-does-not-support-c-extension-loading), which may have applied to Python2.

Also, there seemed to have been proposed [other solutions for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787700/unable-to-locate-the-spatialite-library-django) using `cyqlite`