# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SpatiaLite requires SQLite to be configured to allow extension loading OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157479/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-spatialite-requires-sqlite-to-be-co#) but I am getting Segmentation fault: 11 when migrating in Django.
When I remove PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS when installing Python, I am getting this error.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SpatiaLite requires SQLite to be configured to allow extension loading

Mac OS Version 11.1(Big Sur)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/#macos

Comment: I already tried all of these, still does not work.